# Spring Boot exception handler with Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a spring boot 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT app that has Spring Security.  I have a @ControllerAdvice class for using in handling exceptions from my endpoints, and that works well.  However, I am unable to track exceptions from Spring Security such as AuthenticationException.  I use this to catch those exceptions and log a specific message:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw new SessionAuthenticationException(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

The exception is never caught even though I have this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class BaseController {
    @ExceptionHandler({SessionAuthenticationException.class})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity getSessionAuthenticationExceptionResponse(Exception exception) {

        LOGGER.error("exception.getMessage()", exception);
        return  ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED )
                        .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).body( exception.getLocalizedMessage() );

    }
..}
```

And here is my configuration:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@SpringBootApplication
public class EDentalManager extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {
...
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .addFilterAfter(new CSRFTokenGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
          ...
          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/loginPage")
          .permitAll()
          .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/?tab=success")
          .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
          .and()
          .logout().addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler).logoutRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
          .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
          .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll().and().csrf()
          .and()  
          .sessionManagement()
          .withObjectPostProcessor(new AdditionalStrategyPostProcessor(new CleanRegistry(sessionRegistry)))
           .sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
           .maximumSessions(1)
           .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
           .expiredUrl("/login?expired" )
           .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry )
           .and()
           .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
           .invalidSessionUrl("/")
           .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

What is the best way to trap Spring Security exceptions so I can message the user in case of too-many sessions, authentication exceptions, etc?

**Update** based upon latest findings:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messages;

    @Autowired
    private LocaleResolver localeResolver;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                                        final AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final Locale locale = localeResolver.resolveLocale(request);
        String errorMessage = buildErrorMessage(response, exception, locale);
        response.setHeader("Authentication Error", errorMessage);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), errorMessage);
    }

    private void buildErrorMessage(final HttpServletResponse response, Exception exception, Locale locale) {

               String errorMessage = messages.getMessage("message.badCredentials", null, locale);
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());

    if (exception instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
        errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.invalid.credentials", null, locale);
    } else if (exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("User is disabled")) {
        errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.disabled", null, locale);
    } else if (exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("User account has expired")) {
        errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.expired", null, locale);
    } else if (exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("blocked")) {
        errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.blocked", null, locale);
    } else {
        errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
    }
}
```

I am now redirected to error.html after my /login POST and I see a 401 ResponseStatus, and I have the header information I put on the response.

This seems like it should be handled without a redirect and with a ResponseEntity, but that doesn't appear the way Spring Boot & Security handle it.  Can anyone suggest a cleaner approach to this messaging authentication events without using Thymeleaf (we are pure http ->json ->Tomcat)?

Comment: Take a look at Take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#exception-translation-filter

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I  updated my question with my findings, but I am still not able to see the actual error messages on my login page.

Comment: What is the exact behaviour you have at the moment - you login (with invalid credentials) using the form and then you get HTTP redirected to a URL like ../error.html ? Or are you on another URL but seeing the content of your error.html template? Are you using Spring-Boot with embedded tomcat or hosting on tomcat as a WAR file?

Comment: In my normal Spring MVC flow, the Controller gets the request, processes it and in case of error returns a ResponseEntity with a code and message, or result if not error.  It would seem cleaner if I could handle login errors the same way.  Since I am using the Spring Boot Login Controller implicitly, my @ControllerAdvice class doesn't ever receive the 'SessionAuthenticationException' or 'BadCredentialsException' so all I have been able to come up with is putting the message and status on the response headers.

Comment: @sonoerin Did you finally figured this out?